# Build facebook folly

Tags: c++, facebook, folly

Can't build folly. Have the next folder structure:

/flint/double-conversion/src

/flint/folly/folly/

Where /flint/folly contains readme and license. As [in the readme](https://github.com/facebook/folly) I set up double-conversion with scons, export flags with

```
export LDFLAGS=-L../../double-conversion/
export CPPFLAGS=-I../../double-conversion/src/
```

from the second folly directory and have nothing working:

```
checking double-conversion/double-conversion.h presence... no
checking for double-conversion/double-conversion.h... no
configure: error: Couldn't find double-conversion.h,
```

Also have tried absolute paths like /home/username/flint/double-conversion/ and this doesn't work too.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem while building fbthrift which depends on facebook folly.
It took me some time but i have found the problem which leads to build problems with the double-conversion library.

Undo all the changes of this commit and it will build successful.
https://github.com/facebook/folly/commit/56e0ec4fe2db38106311b09b88820a99860664f3#diff-0aeb0bf602d25a066eb2233e06c4a981

I hope this will also work for you if you still have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my "workaround" for using Folly on CentOS 7;

1. got double-conversion from https://github.com/google/double-conversion
2. built (using scons) which already symlinks from /usr/lib for the .so's
3. symlink'd from the double-conversion/src folder to /usr/include

At least that worked for me.

Comment: Actually, having just tried it on a plain vanilla install and failing I suspect I had something else in there that made it work. I just tried with the RPM instead (http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/28467088/dir/redhat_el_7/com/double-conversion-2.0.1-3.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) and that works like a charm

Answer (score -1):

FWIW,

I was able to get past this by creating a symlink "double-conversion" to the src directory. Effectively, I have .../folly/double-conversion/double-conversion . Now it seems to find the .h file (double-conversion/double-conversion.h with CPPFLAGS=-I...folly/double-conversion)

Unfortunately, I'm having as many troubles on the next step....finding the double-conversion library.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, I see that you have answered this question but be warned your answer includes a question it self which will most likely lead to it being flagged/down voted. I suggest you edit your answer to remove the last part. I would do it myself but I want the changes to be what you want :0